# where is __aeabi_f2lz implemented?

Tags: android-ndk, linker, clang

I have a library which depend on a static library(libexample.a) that I get from third party.
My build failed at linking stage complain about __aeabi_f2lz is undefined. I checked the static lib and it has a undefined symbol __aeabi_f2lz. I would expect this symbol could be resolved while linking.

Also, if I add code like this in my library:

```
volatile float fixme_float = 1.3f;
volatile int64_t fixme_int64 = static_cast<int64_t>(fixme_float);
```

The linking error disappear. I think the above code forced a use of __aeabi_f2lz and mysteriously solved the linking error. I suspect that this is just a linking order issue.

Does anyone know which library contains the implementation of __aeabi_f2lz? I want to force dependency to the library after link the static lib to see if I can solve the issue. Or am I even right to claim that this is because of linking order? I am using Android NDK's standalone arm toolchain.

Thanks for help!

Update[1]:
The build command is:

```
third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang++ -shared -Wl,--fatal-warnings \
    -fPIC -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--as-needed \
    --gcc-toolchain=third_party/android_tools/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64 \
    -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--icf=all -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--exclude-libs=libgcc.a \
    -Wl,--exclude-libs=libc++_static.a -Wl,--exclude-libs=libvpx_assembly_arm.a \
    --target=arm-linux-androideabi -Werror -nostdlib \
    --sysroot=.third_party/android_tools/ndk/platforms/android-16/arch-arm  \
    -Wl,-wrap,calloc -Wl,-wrap,free -Wl,-wrap,malloc -Wl,-wrap,memalign \
    -Wl,-wrap,posix_memalign -Wl,-wrap,pvalloc -Wl,-wrap,realloc -Wl,-wrap,valloc \
    -Lthird_party/android_tools/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a \
    -o "./lib.unstripped/libexample.so" -Wl,-soname="libexample.so"
```

Comment: I don't actually see any objects being linked in that command. I'm expecting to see something like `clang++ -lgcc -lmylib`, where mylib is a static library. If that were the case, libgcc would be checked before mylib gets linked, which means it would never pick things up from libgcc. You can also add `-v` to the linking command to get clang to tell you the full linker command line, which can be helpful for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's in libgcc:

```
$ readelf -sW $NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/libgcc.a | grep __aeabi_f2lz
    24: 00000000    56 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __aeabi_f2lz
```

This is linked by default though. You might have something wrong with your linking order. Could you update your answer to include the command you're using to link your library?

Comment: I included the command in my question. We use gold linker and libgcc.a is excluded from the command line: -Wl,--exclude-libs=libgcc.a Not sure if this is the issue?

Comment: `--exclude-libs` doesn't actually prevent them from being linked. It just prevents the symbols from being re-exported by making them LOCAL instead of GLOBAL (yeah, terrible name for the flag). It's still generally what you want with libgcc though.